# Problem with parsing json data from API in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I'm trying to get parse json data from REST API in node.js with express and mongodb and then display it like userdata. The problem is no matter what I tried it won't parse the data it will either throw and exception like 
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments.
Or it just displays null. I am trying to parse this json data: 
{"userData":{"_id":"5d3c29fdb1b0fd22182ae683","personName":"Damian","userIdentificationEMAIL":"dbonda@gmail.com","dateofbirth":"14.07.2000","grad":"Los Angeles","postanskibroj":"2B","ulica":"Jackovina","drzava":"California","faiID":"123456789","nacionalniID":"000"},"request":{"type":"GET","url":"http://localhost:3000/products"}}
the request field in the json data isn't actually needed for anything I just don't know If I should leave it out or not...someone commented that it's falsely refrenced. Also I can put the whole userData in an array when it get's fetched from the API If that helps.

I have tried quicktype but to no avail, I've tried many examples and ways from stack and generally from the net but I'm getting no where.

I'm managing to get the data from the API but failing short to actually get it parsed and then use it to display the user it's data.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final userData = userDataFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

UserData userDataFromJson(String str) => UserData.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userDataToJson(UserData data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UserData {
    List<UserDatum> userData;
    Request request;

    UserData({
        this.userData,
        this.request,
    });

    factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new UserData(
        userData: new List<UserDatum>.from(json["userData"].map((x) => UserDatum.fromJson(x))),
        request: Request.fromJson(json["request"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "userData": new List<dynamic>.from(userData.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "request": request.toJson(),
    };
}

class Request {
    String type;
    String url;

    Request({
        this.type,
        this.url,
    });

    factory Request.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Request(
        type: json["type"],
        url: json["url"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "url": url,
    };
}

class UserDatum {
    String id;
    String personName;
    String userIdentificationEmail;
    String dateofbirth;
    String iDPhoto;
    String grad;
    String postanskibroj;
    String ulica;
    String drzava;
    String faiId;
    String nacionalniId;

    UserDatum({
        this.id,
        this.personName,
        this.userIdentificationEmail,
        this.dateofbirth,
        this.iDPhoto,
        this.grad,
        this.postanskibroj,
        this.ulica,
        this.drzava,
        this.faiId,
        this.nacionalniId,
    });

    factory UserDatum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new UserDatum(
        id: json["_id"],
        personName: json["personName"],
        userIdentificationEmail: json["userIdentificationEMAIL"],
        dateofbirth: json["dateofbirth"],
        iDPhoto: json["iDPhoto"],
        grad: json["grad"],
        postanskibroj: json["postanskibroj"],
        ulica: json["ulica"],
        drzava: json["drzava"],
        faiId: json["faiID"],
        nacionalniId: json["nacionalniID"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "personName": personName,
        "userIdentificationEMAIL": userIdentificationEmail,
        "dateofbirth": dateofbirth,
        "iDPhoto": iDPhoto,
        "grad": grad,
        "postanskibroj": postanskibroj,
        "ulica": ulica,
        "drzava": drzava,
        "faiID": faiId,
        "nacionalniID": nacionalniId,
    };
}
```

I just need to parse the data and display it in a List or a Text and be able to drop it in a variable and use it troughout the app. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank You.
Cheers!

Comment: It looks like you are expecting to get a list of users from the API, yet the example JSON you show only contains one, with no evidence of `[]` characters introducing a JSON array. Is there a different API call the returns several users? If there's only one, your code can be simplified a bit as it doesn't need to try to build a list.

Comment: @RicharHeap I added braces [] to the api request and now it looks like this {"userData":[{"_id":"5d3c29fdb1b0fd22182ae683","personName":"Damian","userIdentificationEMAIL":"dbonda@gmail.com","dateofbirth":"14.07.2000","iDPhoto":"uploads\\1564223997727wraith.jpg","grad":"Los Angeles","postanskibroj":"2B","ulica":"Jackovina","drzava":"California","faiID":"123456789","nacionalniID":"000"}]}
but yeah I'm actually trying to fetch just user data for a specific user so I only get one user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your change to the JSON text to contain a JSON array, your code should work.

It would be more elegant to change the factory constructor as follows:

```
  factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserData(
        userData: json["userData"]
            .map<UserDatum>((x) => UserDatum.fromJson(x))
            .toList(),
        request: Request.fromJson(json["request"]),
      );
```

Access fields like this:

```
  print(UserData.fromJson(decode).userData[0].dateofbirth);
```

Comment: I tried, how do i get like a particular field? I'm trying to get personName dateofbirth...I tried   fetchData() async{
    Response response;
    response = await get("the local host url");
    var json = jsonDecode(response.body);
    UserData _userDataList = UserData.fromJson(json);
    print(_userDataList.userData.dateofbirth);
  }

Comment: When I tried this code I just get a null in the console   fetchData() async{
    Response response;
    response = await get("http://0c58b08f.ngrok.io/userdata/dbonda@gmail.com");
    var json = jsonDecode(response.body);
    UserDatum _userDataList = UserDatum.fromJson(json);
    print(_userDataList.personName);

  }

Comment: As your API returns a JSON array, you are mapping this to a Dart array (albeit with one entry) so you need to say which user you want to reference - i.e. the zero'th.

Answer (score 0):

You have `syntax error` in your `json data`.

I checked it on the data you posted with the question.

Try to **generate dart code for your classes** by visiting 
[here](http://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart)

you will get an `Autogenerated` Class first then sub classes.

**EDIT**

---

as you changed the question by posting error free json code,changed the answer little bit

---

You can rename `Autogenerated` class but make sure you change it in the below method as well

then pass your json data do function like mentioned below

```
fetchData() async{
  Response response;
  response = await get("yourURL");
  var json = jsonDecode(response.body);
  List<Autogenerated> _userDataList = Autogenerated.fromJson(json); 
}
```

Comment: on the     List<Autogenerated> _userDataList = Autogenerated.fromJson(json);
I am getting an error that Autogenerated can't be assigned to List<Autogenerated> I tried adding a cast and swapping it to just Autogenerated but In the console I only get Instance of Autogenerated when I print(_userDataList);